# How do l reduce the load time of an ecommerce site developed using wordpress and hosted on xampp

Tags: php, wordpress, performance

l am developing an ecommerce site using wordpress and its hosted on xampp. l am using a theme called revo.The free themes on the wordpress install loads on time but immediately l activate the revo theme every page begins to drag(admin dashboard and theme frontend). l have increased memory in the config and php.ini. l have installed wp super cache plugin. it still takes a long time to load. any suggestions please

Comment: Are you running PHP's OPcache extension? If not, try enabling that extension, which is commonly used in production and not so much in development environments. These days, it's a must-have. It will speed up the themes/plugins and WordPress core itself.

Aside from that, consider using one of the 'minify' plugins to minimize the number of JS/CSS files that need to be loaded by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're using images with big sizes ! try optimizing them with [Smush](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/)